# How can I assign a context menu to a toolstrip menu item in winform?

Tags: winforms, contextmenustrip

I have a ToolStrip with a ToolStripDropDownButton to which I am adding ToolStripMenuItems in run time in my code. I need to have a default ContextMenuStrip and assign it to each menu item so when the user right clicks a menu item he will get that context menu strip.
Is it possible ?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't see any straightforward way of doing it.Toolstripmenu item is very much similar to contextmenuitem.But I'm pretty much sure there must be a way by using Windows API.

Comment: It is inappropriate UI.  No user will ever think that right-clicking a menu item will do anything.  There's no point in creating undiscoverable UI, just add a sub-menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution at: [enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7130ea4c-5290-4a3b-9f99-bf9a3e775f0c/adding-contextmenu-menu-to-a-toolstripmenuitem)

To save you the reading I also add the solutuin here:

```
void MenuItemContext(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) return;

        ToolStripMenuItem mID = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

        ContextMenu tsmiContext = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem Item1 = new MenuItem();
        MenuItem Item2 = new MenuItem();

        Item1.Text = "Item1";
        Item2.Text = "Item2";

        tsmiContext.MenuItems.Add(Item1);
        tsmiContext.MenuItems.Add(Item2);

        Item1.Click += new EventHandler(Item1_Click);
        Item2.Click += new EventHandler(Item2_Click);

        hndPass = mID.Text;

        tsmiContext.Show(menuStrip1, menuStrip1.PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)));
    }

    private String hndPass;

    void Item1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MenuItem mID = (MenuItem)sender;
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + mID.Text + " in the context menu of " + hndPass);
    }
    void Item2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mID = (MenuItem)sender;
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + mID.Text + " in the context menu of " + hndPass); ;
    }
```

Have fun (-:

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I worked out something useful,this is obviously not perfect but should give you a decent starting point.I assume you've a ContextMenuStrip named **contextmenustrip1**,some drop down items of which one is **aaaToolStripMenuItem**.Then create a private boolean field,

```
private static bool clickReleased=false;
```

In the MouseDown event of **aaaTool...** write the following code;

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   clickReleased = true;
```

then in MouseUp event,write this;

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
   if (clickReleased)
      {
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
        clickReleased = false;
      }
   }
```

Hope this helps.